# Count the number of words starting with all the alphabets in python

Tags: python, list

Read a file and output the number of words that start with each letter. We want to count the total number of (nonunique) words that begin with that letter for every letter.
I've done something like this-

```
import string

alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}

text = open("I:\\udemy\\Assignment 0.txt", "r")
for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
  
    line = line.lower()
  
    words = line.split(" ")
    
    count = 0
    
    for word in words:
        for i in alphabet:
            if word[0] == i:
                count+=1
                print('words starting from'+ i+': {}', .format(count))
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Good luck with the task. You can share with us the code in case you have a question.

Comment: Write a Python script that reads a file and outputs the number of words that start with each letter. We want to count the total number of (nonunique) words that begin with that letter for every letter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question again and indicate what's wrong with the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a **non-matched case** (uppercase and lowercase treated the same). Something like this should work:

```py
import string

filename = "test.txt" # Replace with filename

# Setting up a dictionary of all ascii_lowercase letters to be incremented on each one found
amounts = {letter:0 for letter in string.ascii_lowercase }
with open(filename,'r') as file:
    # reading each line    
    for line in file:
        # reading each word        
        for word in line.split():
            amounts[word[0].lower()] += 1 # Ignore case and increment letter counter
print(amounts)
```

It will give you a dict with each key being the letter, and each value being the amount of times it is the start of a word.

### Example

So with example text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis
obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam
nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit,
tenetur error, harum nesciunt ipsum debitis quas aliquid. Reprehenderit,
quia. Quo neque error repudiandae fuga? Ipsa laudantium molestias eos 
sapiente officiis modi at sunt excepturi expedita sint? Sed quibusdam
recusandae alias error harum maxime adipisci amet laborum. Perspiciatis
```

We get:

```py
{'a': 13, 'b': 1, 'c': 4, 'd': 2, 'e': 12, 'f': 3,
 'g': 0, 'h': 3, 'i': 6, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 4,
 'm': 7, 'n': 5, 'o': 6, 'p': 3, 'q': 7, 'r': 5,
 's': 10, 't': 2, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 0, 'x': 0,
 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I'm actually new in python programming and I'm learning how to use certain libraries. I've edited my question. Please look at it. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this task

```
from collections import Counter

chars = []
with open('data.txt') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        chars.append(line[0])
counter = Counter(chars)
print(counter)
```

Comment: Why not just `chars = Counter()` and then `chars[line[0]] += 1`?